# Why does this sum equal zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, summation

> Let $\gamma$  be a piece-wise, smooth, closed curve. Let $[t_{j+1}, t_{j}]$ be an interval on the curve. Prove, $$\int_{\gamma} z^m dz=0$$

In the proof it states $$\int_{t_{j}}^{t_{j+1}} \gamma^m(t) \gamma'(t)=\frac{1}{m+1} [\gamma^{m+1}(t_{j+1})-\gamma^{m+1}(t_{j})]$$

Which I can see why. Next it claims, $$\int_{\gamma} z^m dz=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} [\frac{1}{m+1} [\gamma^{m+1}(t_{j+1})-\gamma^{m}(t_j)]]=\frac{1}{m+1} [\gamma^{m+1}(b)-\gamma^{m+1}(a)]=0 $$

I understand why it is $0$ but how did they get from the sum to $0$?

Comment: Does the proof seem overly complicated to anyone other than me? It seems to me that if the proof is valid when you subdivide the curve into $n$ intervals, it is just as valid if you subdivide the curve into two intervals (one from $t_0$ to $t_1,$ and another from $t_1$ in the same direction until you reach $t_0$). When you write out the two terms found by integrating over these two intervals (don't bother with $\sum$ notation), you can actually see explicitly each pair of subterms that cancels. (Or even simpler, how about just one interval from $t_0$ all the way around to $t_0$ again?)

Comment: @DavidK I agree the proof seems over complicated.

Comment: If $m\ne-1$. $ $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sum $$\frac{1}{m+1} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \gamma^{m+1}(t_{j+1}) - \gamma^{m+1}(t_{j})$$ telescopes since $$(\gamma^{m+1}(t_{1}) - \gamma^{m+1}(t_{0})) + (\gamma^{m+1}(t_{2}) - \gamma^{m+1}(1)) + \cdots + (\gamma^{m+1}(t_{n}) - \gamma^{m+1}(t_{n-1}))$$
$$=-\gamma^{m+1}(t_0) + (\gamma^{m+1}(t_1) - \gamma^{m+1}(t_1)) + \cdots + (\gamma^{m+1}(t_{n-1}) - \gamma^{m+1}(t_{n-1})) + \gamma^{m+1}(t_{n})$$
$$=-\gamma^{m+1}(t_0) + 0 + \cdots + 0 + \gamma^{m+1}(t_{n})$$
$$=\gamma^{m+1}(t_n) - \gamma^{m+1}(t_0)$$

In particular, $t_0 = a$ and $t_n = b$. Finally since this is a closed curve, $a=b$, and thus the last difference is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Because $\gamma(a)=\gamma(b)$ since $\gamma$ is a closed curve.

Comment: I understand why it is zero just how did they get from the sum to 0?

Comment: Do you mean you don't know how they get to the sum to $$\frac{1}{m+1} ( \gamma^{m+1}(b) - \gamma^{m+1}(a))?$$

Comment: See Joel's answer.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean.